# How to scroll a link from a list to the top of the page when clicked?

Tags: jquery

I have a list of links in a div element on the left and I am using ajax.js to load content into a div on the right when a link is clicked. I would now like to add some code which scrolls the clicked link to the top of the browser window, so the all list of links will scroll and the clicked one stays at the top.
my code

html

```
<div id="contentt">
<div id="fleft"><h2><a href="#"> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to

<br><br></a></h1>
<h1><a href="#">the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled <br><br></a></h1>
<h1>the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled <br><br></h1>
  </h1></div>

    <div id="fright"></div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#fleft h2').click(function(){
    $('#fright').load('teste.html');
});
})

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fleft h1').click(function(){
        $('#fright').load('teste2.html');

    });
})

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fleft h3').click(function(){
        $('#fright').load('teste3.html');

    });
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/j3rND/)

I can't figure it out how to do these,

Comment: here's a fiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/j3rND/

Comment: Is this your question.when the link is clicked, want to move that div to top of all links correct?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

While clicking the link you can get the `html` of the `link` and then by using `prepend()` can add the link as the first child, also you have to `remove` the link so the it does not appear in two areas. using animate you can scroll to top of div

```
$('#fleft h3').click(function () {
    $('#fright').load('teste3.html');
    //gets the html of the link clicked
    var data = $(this).html();
    //removes the clicked link
    $(this).remove();
    //adds the clicked link to the top of the div
    $('#fleft').prepend(data);
    $('#fleft').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 600);
});
```

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3rND/3/)

Comment: thank you for your help but I would like the ul to scroll so the clicked link goes to the top by scrolling, instead of just jump to the top. can you help me with it? thank you so much.

Comment: is the scroll of the corresponding link should be visible or just scroll to top of the container when link is clicked

Comment: yes it should be visible, so the link I clicked will the first the user can see

Comment: also, I would like the link stays clickable instead of removing the link, thank you so much for helping me. I've been searching this for days

Comment: they are doing a lot of calculation, initially they are finding the window position and checking where the link is located then moving the link correspondingly, if you inspect and search for `tip_trigger` in script, can figure out what is going on, they are also using nicescroll too.

Comment: I forgot that idea, I just have one question: is it possible to scroll the div with the links(#fleft) like 50px everytime a link is clicked? I tried this code: $('#fleft a').click(function(){
    $('#fleft').animate({scrollTop: '+=50'});
}); but is not working, thank you